# How to code Android for the visually impaired?

Tags: android, accessibility

Does Android support visually impaired users in the same way as HTML alt tags are used to provide input for screen readers on the web?

If so, what is the best practice to code Buttons and ImageViews etc so they can be read by a screen reader?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear on your question. The internet browser, or any applications that rely heavily on HTML rendering are not accessible This quote is taken from [this blog post](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/10/more-accessibility-features-in-android.html).

> You can turn on the accessibility features by going to Settings --> Accessibility and checking the box "Accessibility". While the web browser and browser-based
>   applications do not yet "talk" using these enhancements, we're working on them for upcoming releases.

Android does provide screen reader support for a lot of applications, see [this wiki page](http://spielproject.info/projects/spiel/wiki/Accessible_apps) for a list of applications known to work well with Android using a free and open source screen reader.

I can't find any general guidelines for creating accessible apps but [this LinkedIn group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=2534153) may be helpful. I don't have a LinkedIn account though so don't know how active the group is.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your links. My specific question relates to this bullet point from the first link (blog post) that you provided:

"Application authors can easily ensure that their applications remain usable by blind and visually impaired users by ensuring that all parts of the user interface are reachable via the trackball; and all image controls have associated textual metadata."

So my question is simply this: what does it mean to ensure that all image controls have associated textual metadata? How does one code an ImageView or ImageButton with the associated textual metadata?

Comment: See answer below; the contentDescription attribute is likely what you're after here.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource I've found on the Android Accessibility API is this code walk through: https://sites.google.com/site/gdevelopercodelabs/android/accessibility

Comment: This is probably not what the OP wants: these are examples of using the APIs from the *other* side - ie creating an accessibility tool or service, such as a screenreader, rather than creating an app that is itself accessible to a screenreader. Generally speaking, an app should just work with VoiceOver. It shouldn't be necessary to enable any additional accessibility services (other than VoiceOver in the first place) to make an app work.

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/accessibility.html for plenty of details on writing an accessible app.

The nearest equivalent to HTML's ALT is the [contentDescription](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription) property - set in code or in XML.

If you are creating you own custom control, you'll need to do a bit more work to specify other details too; more details at the link above.

Most important thing: when you're done, test with TalkBack, the free Android screenreader from Google. (It's pre-installed on some Android models, but you can download from Android Market if you don't already have it.) You should be able to navigate to all the interactive elements in your app using the directional pad alone, and TalkBack should read out appropriate values for all elements as it does so. (It should pick up the contentDescription and read it out here.)

One thing to watch for is that from what I remember, the screenreader only reads out things that you can navigate to, so if you have instructional text on the page, it may not read out, so you may need to ensure that the contentDescription for other controls is suitably descriptive. To be sure, test with TalkBack, and see for you self (er, hear for yourself!) if what is read out makes sense.

(As noted in one of the other replies, although Android has an accessibility API, the Android browser doesn't actually support it (yet), so HTML pages - even properly marked up HTML code - isn't accessible on Android using the default browser. There are a couple of 3rd party browsers that add accessibility to HTML, though, such as the free IDEAL Web Reader app, which appears to wrap the Android HTML control and then add voicing on top of it. Hopefully Android will make their default browser fully accessible in some later release...)